# Why did devise create a non-empty default email and encrypted password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Running Rails 3.2.8, devise 2.1.2.

I noticed that the migration contains blank defaults:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""
      ......
```

But that schema.rb contains something else:

```
  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  :default => "''''", :null => false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     :default => "''''", :null => false
    .....
```

And these defaults, `''''`, are showing up in my registration forms, etc.  Why does this happen?  Is there any risk to changing these defaults with another migration?

Comment: My `schema.rb` still has the default set to "" but in my sqlite database, the default is "''''". I cleared this default inside the database to no avail.

Comment: I firstly don't understand why devise sets `:default => ""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can change the defaults with no problem.

One of my schema.rb file have this lines (which I think is working fine):

```
  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                               :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",   :limit => 128, :default => "", :null => false
```

Comment: Accepted because SO pressures us to do so, but I never discovered why this happened.